# Help understanding the proof of $A^\circ \cap B^\circ = (A\cap B)^\circ $ in a topology text

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So $(A \cap B)^{\circ}=A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$.

I was reading the following proof:

[image]

I need help understanding the second part. I don't know if it's a typo, but it seems to me that the conclusion $(A\cap B)^{\circ} \subseteq A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$ is reached both times and that doesn't complete the result.

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo, the last inclusion should be the other way.

Comment: I wonder where you find this text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo, the last line should be
$$\text{ we have } A^\circ \cap B^\circ \subseteq (A\cap B)^\circ.$$

Indeed, in the previous line they comment that $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$ is open and is inside $A\cap B$. Since $(A\cap B)^\circ$ is the largest open subset inside $A\cap B$, it must contains $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$.